# Solution space of a system and its rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

If I know that A is an m by n matrix, B is an n by m matrix, rank(A) = rank(B) = rank(AB) = m and that AB = I_m: how can I show that the solution space of Ax=0 is the same as for (BA)x = 0 and how can I find rank(BA).

Any hints or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, hints:

For the first part left multiply $BAx=0$ on both sides with $A$.

For the second part, the solution space of $Ax=0$ is the null-space of $A$. The null-space of $A$ is always a subset of the null-space of $BA$ (for any $B$ such that $BA$ is defined), the row-space of $BA$ is always a subset of the row-space of $A$. Now the dimension of the null-space is the nullity, and the dimension of the row-space is the rank of the matrix, and we have nullity + rank = n (number of columns) for both $A$ and $BA$.